# How to populate a TextBox value when an item is selected from a DataGridViewComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access-2007

I would like to show a product balance in a TextBox when a product is selected from DataGridView.

When product is selected and the tab button is pressed then the product balance should be shown in the TextBox.

All the data is loaded from an Microsoft Access database. How can i achieve this.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridView1_KeyPress);
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1) //Desired Column
    {
        //getSum() function gives sum of a db table column
        textBox1.Text = getSum();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this? Show us your effort?

Comment: I am a newb to c# please guide me for this method..

Comment: what does getSum() do? There is a SelectionChanged event in the DataGridView which will fire everytime a different row is clicked or changed via keyboard. have you looked at that?

Comment: as mentioned getSum() method give sum of a db table's column

Comment: here is my form layout and what i want... http://mcilvia.site40.net/showbalance.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time this was done .......and i am posting this for other user too!
My Question was 
"**I would like to show a product balance in a TextBox when a product is selected from DataGridView. When product is selected and the tab button is pressed then the product balance should be shown in the TextBox. All the data is loaded from an Microsoft Access database. How can i achieve this."
I think the subject is "how to show textbox value when datagridview combobox value is selected"

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
        {
            myCon.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT sum_stock_purchase_quantity, sum_stock_purchase_quantity_thaan from productPurchaseQuery where stock_product_id=" + this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "");

            cmd1.Connection = myCon;
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    textBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["sum_stock_purchase_quantity"]);
                    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["sum_stock_purchase_quantity_thaan"]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBox9.Text = "0.0";
                textBox2.Text = "0.0";
            }
            myCon.Close();
```

Guys i did this. But this may be good or bad. But my objective is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a KeyDown and a KeyUp event Handler to the DataGridView Or your Form or whatever can has focus on the time ;).
When the Key, which is pressed down is Tab i would set a member variable to true or false.

Here a short example of what i mean.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool isTabPressed = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.KeyDown += button1_KeyDown;
        button1.KeyUp += button1_KeyUp;

    }

    void button1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) 
        {
            isTabPressed = true;
        }
    }

    void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) 
        {
            isTabPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else you can do in your method, that you are currently writing and just check if isTabPressed is true.

Hope this helps.
If not leave a comment ;)

EDIT:

So something like this ?
Currently what it does is: you choose something and when you press tab it writes it to the textbox:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    editControlWasOpened = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1 != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null && editControlWasOpened )
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    }
    valueischanged = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bango...But i want values from db to assigned to textbox1 based on the value selected in datagridview product column.. as mentioned in above URL..

Comment: @wajahatdaar2: _above URL_ is faulty

Comment: yes bro the link went DOWN.....I have edited the main Question and posted the pic there

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, based on the value you select in you ComboBox, getSum() wiill go and retrieve the total value from the database. If that's the case then add a SelectedIndexChanged event but casting the DataGridViewComboBoxCell into a ComboBox like the code below.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var combobox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (combobox != null)
    {
        combobox.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var combobox = sender as ComboBox;
    if (combobox != null)
    {
        var item = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmtpy(item))
        {
            textBox1.Text = getSum();
            // Adjust the line above as per your requirement. 
            // I don't fully understand what getSum() does as you haven't posted it
        }
    }
}
```